# “the room whose door is broken” vs “the room which door is broken”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, relative-pronouns

Which exactly is the difference in meaning and usage between choosing *whose* versus choosing *which* in this first sentence?

1. He chose to live in the room [ **which** / **whose** ] door was broken.

How do these compare with this second sentence?

2. He chose to live in the room, the door of which was broken.

Comment: [The American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=whose) says *The tradition holds that **whose** should function only as the possessive of **who**, and be limited in reference to persons. Nonetheless, **whose** has been used to refer to inanimate things since the 1300s, and it appears in the works of many illustrious writers, including **Shakespeare, Milton,** and **Wordsworth**.* With writers like that endorsing the usage, pedants don't really have a leg to stand on!

Answer (score 3):

> The room with the broken door ...

Sounds better.

Answer (score 3):

This one catches natives all the time.

'Whose' is *correct* but feels wrong. We don't have a 'whiches' to match, but 'which' is definitely wrong too. In speech, no-one cares, really, but when written, people often try really hard to recast their sentence to avoid it.

You have to bite the bullet & use 'whose' for inanimate objects too, or recast to duck the issue.
<sub>I've used arrows to try eliminate potential confusion over which comment belongs to which sentence.</sub>

> He chose to live in the room, the door of which was broken.

↑ Correct but ugly.

> He chose to live in the room whose door was broken.

↑ Correct but somehow slightly uncomfortable.

> He chose to live in the room which door was broken.

↑ Completely unacceptable.

↓ Recast

> He chose to live in the room with the broken door.