# "I was blown away by how good that movie was!" — If we took "by" away, would the sentence meaning remain the same?

Tags: meaning, difference

[thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+away):
**(1)** *I was blown away **by** how good that movie was*!

As far as I understand, if we took "by" away, the sentence would also remain correct:
**(2)** *I was blown away how good that movie was*!

I wonder if there's any difference between (1) and (2).

Comment: #2 is idiomatic in AmE (as is #1).   "I was surprised how well he did."

Comment: ***blown away*** here is syntactically the same as ***surprised, astonished, amazed,...*** The proposition (***at, by,*** and possibly others) is *optional*.

Comment: @TimR: There's no US/UK usasge split here. If you switch from UK to US corpus on [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+surprised+how+much%2Cwas+surprised+by+how+much%2Cwas+surprised+at+how+much&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), nothing much changes.

Comment: For some reason, to my ear "I was surprised how well he did" sounds totally idiomatic while "I was blown away how good the movie was" sounds un-idiomatic. That said, I'm really struggling to come up with any rationalization on why that should be the case. Could it be that this syntax is rarely used outside of certain verbs, so I haven't learned to generalize it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just didn't want to assume, and didn't want to rely on ngrams after BillJ informed me, on a different question, that " 'like' does not license a content clause on its own, at least not in BrE" but ngrams for BrE 2019 shows the construction as well-attested, and yet there's no way to check out the BrE sources on which the ngram is based, since the buttons at the bottom aren't for BrE.

Comment: @YonKuma:  What does your ear say if you substitute "flabbergasted" or "taken aback"?

Comment: @TimR Good test. That also hits me as wrong, though the more times I repeat the sentence in my head the less certain I feel about it.

Comment: @TimR: I understand. My comment was primarily for the benefit of learners, who I think are often too quick to assume AmE/BrE usages are more common and more significant than is actually the case. There are a few well-known cases with common nouns and verbs, but in an Internet-enabled world, only the most common of those will survive long. Like irregular verbs, any relatively uncommon examples tend to rapidly disappear.

Comment: *I'm **discombobulated** how odd it seems not to include a preposition here.* (Well, actually, I'm not! :)

Comment: @YonKuma How about with a dummy **it**?     *It was flabbergasting|surprising|astonishing|discombobulating how well he did.*  ?

Comment: @Yonkuma I think that it sounds marginal to you may be because there's no deverbal (past participial) **ed**-suffixed adjective formed from the passive use of transitive phrasal verb "blow away".    That's why I wondered about "taken aback".

Comment: @TimR I'm not sure that's the case. "I was entranced how beautiful she looked" sounds deeply incorrect to me. How does that sentence strike you?

Comment: There won't be special syntactic categories for verbs that do or don't "require" a preposition between the verb and a ***how** ADJECTIVE something is* phrase. Most individual speakers will draw the line *somewhere* between "sounds okay" and "sounds weird", but that's really just personal preference.

Comment: @YonKuma:   does changing "she looked" to "she was" have any effect?

Comment: The **en** prefix of **entranced** indirectly emphasizes the agency role in the state.  Asking for a "by". Maybe.

Comment: @TimR No, it has no effect. I think that FumbleFingers is correct, and my brain is just accepting or denying on a verb by verb basis. Some verbs are allowed to do this and some aren't, and for me it seems entirely based on whether I've head other people using that syntax with that verb.

Comment: In speech, speakers drop stuff all the time. Thus, a speaker might drop **by** here, but if you asked her/him, on second thought, they would probably agree they meant to use the **by**. The idiom *is* **to be blown away by something** after all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "blown away here is syntactically the same as surprised, astonished, amazed" Yes, and therefore as passives require by x.

Comment: @Lambie: It's not "syntactically the same as surprised, astonished, amazed" that matters here. It's the status of ***how-*** clauses in the cited usage context. And the usage chart I posted under DJClayworth's answer clearly shows there are plenty of people who don't accept your "requirement" in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ngrams is not a grammarian. Just  because one sees it without by does not make it usual.

Comment: Ho-hum. Next you'll be telling me [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/surprised) isn't "a grammarian". They specifically give the prepositionless example usage ***You’d be surprised how many people voted for him.*** Besides which, surely *by definition* something that accounts for almost 1/3rd of all relevant usages must be "usual", even if you think it's "incorrect".

Comment: @Lambie: in grammatical terms, it's whether the phrasal verb "blow away", when used in an "I am *blown away*" construction, licenses a clausal complement headed by "how" as an alternative to a prepositional phrase, and that licensing isn't purely a matter of personal preference. What "sounds OK" is far more complex than personal preference.  Language is constantly changing.

Comment: @TimR: I'm not convinced it's a good idea to talk about "valid" and "invalid" in contexts like this. Clearly it's like [*Can you use **whose** with inanimate subjects?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344716/), where different people react differently to "borderline" cases. But there's a risk that *learners* will end up committing themselves to "stylistic choices" that *used* to be more common, simply because they're the ones more likely to be presented as "correct" even as they're dying out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know what you mean by "like this".  I certainly haven't used the word "valid" or "invalid".

Comment: @TimR It is not "blow away". He blew away the dust from the shelf. It is the idiom: **to be blown away by something**. Like I said, people leave words out. Happens all the time in speech. And I use what I have internalized, not what I find in ngrams. Like I said, people **leave things out all the time in speech**.

Comment: @Lambie:  It is "blow away" but cast in the passive.  *Their amazing acrobatics blew me away. I was blown away by their amazing acrobatics.*

Comment: Check out the difference in Ludwig Guru for by and not by: https://app.ludwig.guru/s/blown+away+how

Comment: That site has a logon requirement. The issue is is whether the agent in the passive construction can be a "naked" content-clause: *I was blown away by how high the acrobats leapt* or *I was blown away how high the acrobats leapt.*   Is "blown away" an adjectival form there derived from the past-participial form of the phrasal verb?

Comment: @TimR Frankly, I find it rather silly since all passives in English standardly take by. So leave it out if you will but it is not standard.

Comment: @YonKuma: Rather surprisingly (to me, at least), it seems that in this particular context, the "simpler" (prepositionless) form was [more common in the past.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+amazed+how%2Cwas+amazed+at+how%2Cwas+amazed+by+how&year_start=1900&year_end=1940&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) There's not space in this comment for another link, but if you change the date range on that one to the most recent 20 years, you may be surprised how much has changed! I disagree with others here because they're being dogmatic, but I'd ***advise*** learners to use a preposition.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/blow-away The **difference** is written vs. spoken.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surprised+how%2Csurprised+by+how%2Cblown+away+how%2Cblown+away+by+how&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 any hits for "blown way how” are false positives. Both versions "surprised by how" and "surprised by how“ are equally popular

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your two versions are the same. Did you mean "surprised how" for one of them?

Comment: @gotube I wrote the same thing twice but the ngrams are different. I don't know what happened to the earlier Ngram I posted in a link

Comment: @gotube  Maybe it was only one link, I can't remember,  but the four phrases in the chart are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unquestionably, the only difference between OP's two examples is *syntactic*, not *semantic*. Some (not all) native Anglophones will find the "prepositionless" version #2 at least "awkward", if not downright *ungrammatical.*

I contend that the *specific* case of the phrasal verb ***blown away*** is simply "less familiar" to us than, say, ***surprised,*** when used without a preposition before ***...how** [adjective something is]*. But whether people like #2 or not, it means the same as #1.

---

[Oxford Learners Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/surprised) is a perfectly sound authority, and they give this example "prepositionless" usage...

> *You’d be surprised how many people voted for him.*

And [here's a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20surprised%20how%20much%2Cwas%20surprised%20by%20how%20much%2Cwas%20surprised%20at%20how%20much&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) comparing that format with two possible prepositions...

[image]

---

TL;DR: As can be seen from comments and other answers, not everyone agrees with the prepositionless usage before an adverbial ***how-*** clause. Presumably that's because when it's a "standard" noun phrase, such as...

> *I was surprised by a loud noise*

...you *can't* omit the preposition. But many people are perfectly happy to say ***how-*** clauses work differently, so it's okay with them.

Anyone who thinks English might support a "rule" whereby ***blown away*** has different syntactic affordances to ***surprised*** is simply mistaken. The specific verb may affect some people's personal preference, but that's just *preference*.

Comment: Those who process **surprised** and **blown away** similarly will hear nothing amiss; those who don't will hear something marginal or ungrammatical.  Some learners will want to know when a significant portion of the population will hear a construction as marginal or ungrammatical, and ngrams are not a particularly apt tool for such questions.

Comment: I have no problem with people saying what they *prefer*. But honestly, people downvoting my answer simply because their preference doesn't align with a usage specifically endorsed by Oxford Learners Dictionaries is a bit ridiculous. And as implied by my previous comment, when people have disagreements like this, it's often an *older, more complex* form they're arguing for, so the net effect is that *learners* end up being steered towards usages that are dying out.

Comment: I downvoted it solely "on procedural grounds" as they say in court.  It's a methodological demerit.  ngrams can show that plenty of speakers use a construction but they don't show that plenty of speakers avoid it, and if they do, why they do.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree. You're entitled to your personal preferences, and I'd never have downvoted your answer if it didn't explicitly distinguish the two possibilities as "correct / incorrect". I don't accept *some people use/prefer the "incorrect" version* as a valid stance to take on a usage like this. That would still be the case even if I hadn't found a dictionary example with no such "warning" - but *with* it, I think it's an open-and-shut case.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surprised+how%2Csurprised+by+how%2Cblown+away+how%2Cblown+away+by+how&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 any hits for "blown way how” are false positives. Both versions "surprised by how" and "surprised by how“ are equally popular

Comment: Ngram 1980 to 2019 with "surprised (by)" omitted; clearly writers prefer the preposition "by" version with blown away. Is it only stylistic? Again, the vast majority of its for "blown away how" are false positives https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blown+away+how%2Cblown+away+by+how&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're misunderstanding. I *do* process **surprised** and **blown away** similarly, so this has nothing to do with my personal preference. It has to do with what ngrams can show and what they can't show.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+surprised+how%2Cwas+surprised+by+how&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @TimR: I'm not trying to use NGrams to prove that prepositionless ***blown away** how [adj noun was]* is "common". I'm using it to prove that the construction is in common use with ***surprised***, and then I'm arguing that since ***surprised / blown away*** are "syntactically equivalent", there's no real argument against prepositionless use of the latter. People can make their own usage choices based on personal preference, but they can't reasonably appeal to some kind of high-level syntactic justification for their choice. It's just "familiarity", which could easily change quite quickly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  But that's what complement "licensing" is all about -- some "high level syntactic justification".  It's what makes some native speakers *feel* that a particular kind of complement is "off".

Comment: I dispute that the "justification" here is really anything more than just the fact that "to be blown away" in this sense is a relatively new usage, and this coupled with the fact that the preposition use is increasing means it's less familiar. That might not be true in a decade or two if for some reason the usage becomes more common and "mainstream" (but it'll probably always be "colloquial, slangy", so that may affect things).

Comment: -1 because this is an answer to the comment thread below the question, not the question itself. The question itself is not about the correctness of "*blown away how*", but about how it's different to "*blown away **by** how*", which is not addressed. Happy to undo it if you tag me

Comment: @gotube: Does the newly-added section at the front do the trick?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yep!